# Cannot connect to server running in session 0 thought service

Tags: c#, process, windows-services

Let me first explain what I'm trying to do; 
I've made a wpf application that installs and (to some degree) manages windows services. These services are also written in c#, and attempt to launch a thirdparty server.

The wpf application works fine, the launching of the server through the newly installed windows service works perfectly fine aswell. Now here comes the problem; even though everything appears to be running perfectly fine, the thirdparty server does not seem to acces the internet.

I launch the process using process.start, like so:

```
        serverProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pi.FileName = args[1]; //exe
        pi.Arguments = args[2]; //start params
        pi.UseShellExecute = false;
        pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pi.ErrorDialog = false;
        pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        serverProcess.StartInfo = pi;
        serverProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(serverProcess_Exited);
        serverProcess.Start();
```

Since this runs in session 0 I don't want it to create a gui. I read the standard output using my managing application, from which I can deduce that the server is in fact running. However, when attempting to connect to it (using localhost) it doesn't even find the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

The point where I get stuck, or rather the server gets stuck, is the point where it needs to connect to a MasterServer. It just hangs there indefinitely and I am at a loss why.

Comment: When you start the third-party server manually, does it prompt you to do anything before it starts listening for connections?  If so, perhaps it is waiting for some sort of input before it fully starts up.

Comment: No, it does not. The server normally runs as a console application and only requires some start paramaters. It then reads further settings from a configuration file. Thanks though!